# Load Scene if System.DateTime.Now is greater than PlayerPrefs value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple date time check. I belive my logic is correct but not the way I am doing it.

What I want to do is when a user starts the app I want to check if it is the first time it has ever been started. If it is the first time I want to stored the system date time, if the app has been ran before time will already have been stored in the `PlayerPrefs` like so:

```
    int timecheck;
            void Start()
            {
                 timecheck = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("savedFirstRun"); //Get time check value

                if (timecheck != 1) { 
                    PlayerPrefs.SetString("rewardCountDown", System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString());
                    timecheck = 1;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("savedFirstRun", timecheck);// set time check value
                }                    
            }
```

I then take the stored system time , `"rewardCountDown"`, and covert the string to date time. I then add the wait time to this date, in this example I add one minute.

```
 DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(PlayerPrefs.GetString("rewardCountDown"));

        //Convert the old time from binary to a DataTime variable
        storedDate = temp;

        storedDate.AddMinutes(1);

    }
```

I then poll the update method to keep checking if the system.time.now is greater than the stored time.

```
    void Update()
    {
        dateNow = System.DateTime.Now;
        if (dateNow > storedDate)
        {
            Canvas2.SetActive(true);            
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Home 4", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }
```

I expected after waiting a minute the sceneManger would fire and load the next Scene. But the scene never loads.

My question is what am I doing wrong? I am thinking it could be how im storing the datetime as a PlayerPref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be as simple as parsing the datetime using the DateTime object.  This might be worth a shot :

```
        DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse(PlayerPrefs.GetString("rewardCountDown"));

        //Convert the old time from binary to a DataTime variable
        storedDate = temp;

        storedDate.AddMinutes(1);
```

Because you're serializing the date using the default ToString(), parsing it back should result in your date converting back to a DateTime object via Parse() without a format.

If that still doesn't work, check out what the string is in your PlayerPrefs by writing it out to the console - then passing in the format to the ParseExact() call as well as the string e.g.

```
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    var temp = DateTime.ParseExact(PlayerPrefs.GetString("rewardCountDown"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", provider);

    storedDate = temp;
```

You'd need to ensure that the format you're using matches your serialized string exactly, but that should do the trick.

More info here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

and here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is one obvious issue : `storedDate.AddMinutes(1)`; doesnt change the value of StoredDate...  Its a common easy missed issue

```
storedDate = storedDate.AddMinutes(1);
```

although I would have expected immediate to load scene, not not done it at all. Where is rewardcountdown set? Theres no setting of that in your code.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help, rewardcountdown is set in my first code example if timecheck is not equal to 1. The formatting was werid so made it hard to see, have fixed it with a edit. I think I see a mistake I have made  in System.DateTime.Now.ToBinary().ToString()); . At a guess I don't need the .ToBinary() as it should be string

Comment: One thing I did find was Converting DateTime to binary, to string, and then back again resulted in String was not recognised as a DateTime format!  Drop the tobinary portion.. just store date/time as a string..

Comment: I think thats it. Not even sure why I put it to Binary. Will test and feedback

Comment: See that puzzles me, looking at your original code because you didnt add a minute to it, you should have immediately gone to the new scene.. suggesting then something else is wrong.

Comment: Ok, so comment on how changed it and we can continue.

Answer (score 0):

you should set timer like that :

```
   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer Timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
```

then in initializer write

```
    Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Click);
Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
Timer.Start();
```

and inside Timer_Click method do your action

```
    private void Timer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// wite your own code
}
```

Comment: How does that make use of the PlayerPrefs? I want to store the start time if the app is then closed and x amount of time passes. The new scene will still load.

Comment: you can save it in environment.curentdirectory and in login time you can read it to load and compare

Comment: Please delete this answer because it is not relevant to Unity

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handled some dates in a game I am working on.

As my statistics natively worked on `long`s and not dates, I encoded the date time as an integer value in such a way that it could be parsed unambiguously.

```
long nl = long.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddHHmm")); //now
long ll = StatisticsTracker.lastDailyLogin.value; //saved value
if(ll > 0) {
    DateTime nowLogin = DateTime.ParseExact(nl.ToString(), "yyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //is this unnecessary? Probably. But this shows both halves of the encoding / decoding process.
    DateTime lastLogin = DateTime.ParseExact(ll.ToString(), "yyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //do stuff
}
```

The long value generated here could be stored in PlayerPrefs easily.

Comparing my code with yours, it looks like you encode your date as a binary string with `.ToBinary()`, but when you parse, you don't insure to parse it *as a binary string.* I recommend picking a format (as I've done) and doing the conversion and parsing using that format.